# IRC: Cannot send to channel: #ruby-lang

Tags: irc

I cannot connect connect to the #ruby-lang channel using an online IRC or my application. I can see what other people are saying, but whenever I type it just says:

```
20:05 <freenode> Error(404): #ruby-lang Cannot send to channel
```

and what does this mean:

```
17:35 Topic: Ruby 2.0.0-p0: http://ruby-lang.org (Ruby 1.9.3-p392) || Paste >3 lines of text on http://gist.github.com
```

I pasted 3 lines of text on http://gist.github.com like a fool. I have no idea what's going on!

Please, some help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101849) is a description of a similar problem in another IRC channel on freenode. Basically, register (using [NickServ](http://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration)) a nickname and then log in using it.

As for the "paste >3 lines...", it is just to get people to not post lots of text on IRC (which is annoying) and use a pastebin/Gist instead.

Comment: link to NickServ updated:  http://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration

Answer (score 5):

Some channels mute unidentified users to prevent spam and abuse (#ruby-lang on freenode is an example). If you want to be able to talk in this channel, you need to [register](http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#nicksetup) an account and identify to it.

If you use the following command:

```
/mode #ruby-lang +q
```

You can see this:

```
#ruby-lang q $~a barjavel.freenode.net 1364171330
```

This [extban](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/extbans) prevents all users not identified to services from speaking in the channel. Note the `~`, which negates the match.

Once you've registered an account, you can identify to NickServ by executing this command on IRC:

> /msg nickserv identify YourAccount YourPassword

To make this process easier, you can use SASL. It's easy to configure and *highly* recommended. The documentation for that is available on freenode's knowledgebase: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl

Comment: the SASL link has been moved?